# Incorrect label type using threeparttable and cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, threeparttable

I'm having an issue with the *threeparttable* package label type, causing *cleverref* to not be able to refer correctly to the table. Compiling on Overleaf produces the following warning: "cref reference format for label type `' undefined on input line 8."

Is there a way to correct the label type for this table? Or another workaround that will allow cleveref to reference correctly?

MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    
    Cleveref reference to threeparttable \cref{tab:test}.
    
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \caption{Caption.}
            \begin{tabular}{l l}
                Header 1 & Header 2 \\
                \hline
                Entry 3 & Entry 4 \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{threeparttable}
        \label{tab:test}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you place the `\label` directive immediately after the `\caption` directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not due to either `cleveref` or `threeparttable` in particular. It happens because you put `\caption` within the `threeparttable` environment and `\label` cannot "see" its effects outside it. You should move `\label` into the environment, after `\caption`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

Cleveref reference to threeparttable \cref{tab:test}.

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Caption.}
  \label{tab:test}
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
      Header 1 & Header 2 \\
      \hline
      Entry 3 & Entry 4 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah such an easy fix, thanks! As it seems to work with the label after all of the table as well, why is it preferable for the label and caption next to each other

Comment: Not for any hard rule, it is just easier not to make this kind of mistake if you maintain the habit of placing the label right after the caption.

Comment: You wrote, "You can either move `\caption` out of the `threeparttable` environment or the `\label` into it." The former suggestion would make using the `threeparttable` environment pretty much pointless. The 3 formal parts of a `threeparttable` environment are the caption, a `tabular`-like environment, and (optionally) a `tablenotes` environment. The machinery of the `tablenotes` package then assures that the widths of the caption and of the tablenotes material don't exceed the width of the tabular env. Hence, it's not good advice to place the caption outside the `threeparttable` environment.

Comment: @user7794764 - Your assertion that "As it seems to work with the label after all of the table as well" is *incorrect*. To verify this counter-claim, take the answer above, insert two copies of `\refstepcounter{figure}` *before* the start of the `table` environment, emove the `\caption` directive from its current location, and place it after the end of the `table` environment instead (to comply with your assertion). Recompile the document twice and take note that `\cref{tab:test}` outputs "fig. 2", *not* "table 1".

Comment: The OP's assertion that "it seems to work with the label after all of the table" is incorrect; see the preceding comment for a demonstration of my counterclaim. Hence, the only correct piece of advice is, in fact, *not* to place `\caption` outside of the environment -- here: a `threeparttable` environment --  that contains the `\caption` directive. (Of course, the `\label` directive also has to be placed after its associated `\caption` directive.)

Comment: @Mico You're right, of course. I have edited to correct the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The same is valid if you use `talltblr` table environment defined in `tabularray` package. It is equivalent of `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

Cleveref reference to \verb+talltblt+ table is \cref{tab:test}.

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Caption.},
  label = {tab:test} % <---
                    ]{cells=l}
Header 1 & Header 2 \\
      \hline
Entry 3 & Entry 4\TblrNote{a}   \\
      \hline
    \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]